# Chrome won't send domain level cookies to server in request header

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

This really annoying, partly because its internal to chrome and its more or less a guessing name. But my request header is not passing along the cookies for the same domain.

I have a cookie with a domain set to

> **.domain.net**

My application is at the following URL

> myapp.**foo.bar.domain.net**

I'm trying to send a request to another server on the same root domain at

> otherapp.**bar.domain.net**

The cookie does not send in Chrome but does send in Safari.

According to the HTTP cookie spec, it should send because ".domain.net" is the master domain both both **.bar.domain.net** and **.foo.bar.domain.net**

Furthermore, I know the domain level cookie is working because when I make a GET request to **myapp.foo.bar.domain.net** or to **myapp.bar.domain.net**, the cookie is indeed passed in the header. It seems to fail in the case when I'm making a request to either domain when the origin is the other.

Does anyone know if this is a known bug in Chrome, I'm running version 59.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was not adding

```
xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
```

In the ajax request. This was a little confusing because this was all working before I changed the domain and whats more confusing is that this works with Safari without needing to set that `withCredentials` header. The take away here is that Chrome will not send cookies if the hostname differs, even when a root domain cookie is set, unless the `withCredentials` header param is passed, however Safari will send no matter what. I don't know about Firefox.